# Send javascript generated texbox values with form(GET) to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form where you can generate automatically additional form boxes and send them to be handeled at PHP-script. How ever as I am quite lousy with Javascript and I am running in the following problem.

When the form is filled out I can see everything is filled out on the URL, except the the boxes created with JS (every box has unique name!). My guess is that the JS generated field drop out of the form tags, but can not figure out how to fix this. I would appreciate if someone could give me pointers or tell me how to fix this. I shortened the code for clarity  (if something got left out please tell me). If someone is wondering why I am not using the form action. It´s because drupal tries to forward the site to wrong place if I do (surprise, not too good with drupal either :D)

```
<?php
require_once('customer.php');
?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var intTextBox=0;

        //FUNCTION TO ADD TEXT BOX ELEMENT

        function addElement()
        {
        intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
        var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
        var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox);
        newTBDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='product'><tr><td>Sku/ID: "+intTextBox+": <input type='text' name='sku_" + intTextBox + "'/></div>";
        contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
        }

        function removeElement()
        {
        if(intTextBox != 0)
        {
        var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
        contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('strText'+intTextBox));
        intTextBox = intTextBox-1;
        }
        }

          </script>
        <table>
         <form name="activate">
        <div class='cu'>
         <tr><td>Sku/ID (oma): <input type="text" name="sku"></td>
         <td><p><a href="javascript:addElement();" >Add product</a> 
       <a href="javascript:removeElement();" >Remove product</a></p></td></tr>
       <div id="content"></div>
      </div>
     <tr> <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td> </tr>

    </form>




     Customer.php
        <?php

        if(isset($_GET["sku_1"]))
        {
        echo "found it";
        }
        else 
        echo "did not find it";

    ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Changed the method to Post, but still nothing from the JS generated boxes (original boxes work fine)

Comment: Can you use jquery? Form tag does not read dynamically added inputs.

Comment: Ok, so that´s the reason. Well I do not have much options then, but to try to use jquery then. Thanks for the answer, that explains a lot :)

Comment: I would use AJAX. The problem with your approach is that PHP is only read when a web page loads or is submitted to based on your HTML `<form action` attribute. This means that your form will clear, and you cannot hold `<input value`s. Although you can use PHP to write JavaScript, you can't just write PHP with Client Side JavaScript. You can however use AJAX, which sends info using JavaScript to your PHP page, based on the `XMLHttpRequest`, creating a partial submission, so the page doesn't reload, avoiding scrolling reset. You don't need a form or a submit button with AJAX, just use `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically change the url of the form tag to include textbox values:

```
var textboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++){
    var data = "?";
    if (textboxes[i].type == "text") {
        data += (data == "?" ? "" : "&") + textboxes[i].name + "=" + textboxes[i].value;
    }
}
form.action += data;
```

I haven't tested this, you might have to dynamically add all elements

[UPDATE]
If you have trouble with the form you can try using an absolute path, if you aren't already.